# Undo/ Redo Implementation using Stack

Tags: python, data-structures, stack, undo-redo, getch

I want to implement Undo-Redo functionality using stacks. When the user presses Ctrl+Z the last node will be removed from the screen. When the user press again Ctrl+Z then the "last.last" node will be removed from the screen and if he presses Ctrl+Y then the last removed node will display again on the screen.

Below is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pointer = None

    def push(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, Node):
            x = Node(x)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.pointer = x

            undo_stack = Stack()
            undo_stack.undo(x)
        else:
            x.next = self.pointer
            self.pointer = x

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print(f'Stack Underflow')
        else:
            self.pointer = self.pointer.next

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.pointer is None

    def __str__(self):
        string = ''
        current = self.pointer
        while current:
            string += f'{current.data}->'
            current = current.next
        if string:
            print(f'Stack Pointer = {self.pointer.data}')
            return f'[{string[:-2]}]'
        return '[]'

    def undo(self, x):
        self.push(x)
        print(x)

    def redo(self, x):
        self.pop(x)
        print(x)


stack = Stack()

stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)
stack.push(4)
stack.push(5)

print(stack)
```

## Implementation

Suppose I have a stack

> Stack: [5->4->3->2->1]

When I press `Control+Z`, the `undo()` function calls the `pop()` function and removes the last added item from the stack.

> 5 popped.
> Stack: [4->3->2->1]

again I press `Control+Z`, then:

> 4 popped.
> Stack: [3->2->1]

When I press `Control+Y` the `redo()` function is called and the previously removed items appear on the terminal.

> 4 pushed.
> Stack: [4->3->2->1]

again I press `Control+Y`, then

> 5 pushed.
> Stack: [5->4->3->2->1]

## Error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I know why this error occurs because inside the `push()` I made a call to the `undo()`, and inside the `undo()` I made a call to the `push()`. What should I do to implement undo-redo functionality, should I make a new class and implement Undo/Redo on that class?

Any ideas/ code will be highly appreciatable.

Comment: perhaps you're implementing a stack as a learning exercise - but why not use collections.deque?

Comment: The idea is not about implementing `collections.deque` or building your own customized `Stack` class. We can also use that though.

Edit: I prefer to build my own Stack class and implement undo-redo functionality on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in this. The main issue causing the infinite recursion is this:

```py
    undo_stack = Stack()
    undo_stack.undo(x)
```

Here, you are combining two different approaches. You could *either* have two separate stacks in your `UndoRedoStack` class and swap elements back and forth when undo/redo is called, *or* you could have a single doubly-linked list of nodes and step up or down the list every time you want to undo/redo. Here, you seem to be doing both, and you are creating an infinite number of `Stack`s in the process.

Instead, all you need to do is add one line:

```py
else:
    x.next = self.pointer
    self.pointer.prev = x  # You forgot this
    self.pointer = x
```

Then, you don't need to make any other stacks. You can just walk up/down the chain in both directions.

There were also a number of other small mistakes that would have prevented the class from working as intended. I've fixed those up here:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Node({self.data})"


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pointer = None

    def push(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, Node):
            x = Node(x)
            
        if self.is_empty():
            self.pointer = x
        else:
            x.next = self.pointer
            self.pointer.prev = x
            self.pointer = x

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            print(f'Stack Underflow')
        else:
            self.pointer = self.pointer.next

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.pointer is None

    def __str__(self):
        string = ''
        current = self.pointer
        while current:
            string += f'{current.data}->'
            current = current.next
        if string:
            print(f'Stack Pointer = {self.pointer.data}')
            return f'[{string[:-2]}]'
        return '[]'

    def undo(self):
        x = self.pointer
        self.pop()
        print(x)

    def redo(self):
        x = self.pointer.prev
        if x is None:
            print("nothing to redo")
        else:
            self.push(x)
            print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stack = Stack()

    stack.push(1)
    stack.push(2)
    stack.push(3)
    stack.push(4)
    stack.push(5)

    print("stack is:")
    print(stack)
    print()

    stack.undo()

    print("after undo:")
    print(stack)
    print()

    stack.redo()

    print("after redo:")
    print(stack)
```

Comment: This fixed it up a lot, but there's still a bug: If you undo all the way to the beginning, redo fails to work because the pointer goes nowhere. The current code makes it like the stack gets deleted at this point. The fix seems easy, and otherwise, this code works well implementing an undo/redo stack.